# Amazon App Submission Internal Server Error

Tags: android, api, amazon-appstore

Hi using information on [Amazon App Submittion API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission-api/python-example.html), I write a python code to upload apk files to Amazon App Store. Although I tried to follow the instructions on the official reference, I could not managed to upload the apk. I always get Internal Server Error[Http 500]. Is there something wrong in my code or is it really issue of amazon servers? (p.s The part that is not working is replace_apk()  function)

```
        import sys
        import requests
        import json
        import os
        from pathlib import Path

        def get_token():
        scope = "appstore::apps:readwrite"
        grant_type = "client_credentials"
        data = {
        "grant_type": grant_type,
        "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
        "scope": scope
        }
        amazon_auth_url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token"
        auth_response = requests.post(amazon_auth_url, data=data)

            auth_response_json = auth_response.json()
            access_token = auth_response_json["access_token"]
            return access_token

        BASE_URL = 'https://developer.amazon.com/api/appstore'
        APP_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        CLIENT_SECRET =  str(sys.argv\[1\])
        ACCESS_TOKEN = get_token()
        ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % ACCESS_TOKEN}
        LOCAL_APK_PATH =  str(sys.argv\[2\])

        def get_edit():
        get_edits_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits' % APP_ID
        get_edits_url = BASE_URL + get_edits_path
        get_edits_response = requests.get(get_edits_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER)
        current_edit = get_edits_response.json()
        return current_edit

        def create_edit():
        create_edit_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits' % APP_ID
        create_edit_url = BASE_URL + create_edit_path
        create_edit_response = requests.post(create_edit_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER)
        new_edit = create_edit_response.json()
        return new_edit

        def replace_apk(edit_id):
        get_apks_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks' % (APP_ID, edit_id)
        get_apks_url = BASE_URL + get_apks_path
        apks = requests.get(get_apks_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER).json()

            firstAPK = apks[0]
            apk_id = firstAPK['id']   
            get_specific_apk_url = BASE_URL + '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks/%s' % (APP_ID, edit_id, apk_id)
            apk = requests.get(get_specific_apk_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER)
            etag = apk.headers['Etag']
            
            replace_apk_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks/%s/replace' % (APP_ID, edit_id, apk_id)
            
            replace_apk_url = BASE_URL + replace_apk_path
            local_apk = open(LOCAL_APK_PATH, 'rb').read()
            apk_file_name = Path(LOCAL_APK_PATH).stem
            all_headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
                'fileName': apk_file_name,
                'If-Match': etag,
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN
            }
            replace_apk_response = requests.put(replace_apk_url, headers=all_headers, data=local_apk)
            return replace_apk_response

        if __name__ == '__main__':
        current_edit = get_edit()
        if not current_edit:
        print("No open Edit")
        current_edit = create_edit()
        print("New Edit is created: ",  current_edit)
        else:
        print("Edit exists")

            if current_edit['status'] == "IN_PROGRESS":
                upload_response = replace_apk(current_edit['id'])
                print(upload_response)
            else:
                sys.exit("Unexpected app state. The app could be in review")
```

I have tried to upload the apk file to Amazon Appstore but getting 500 Error codes

**EDIT**:
I added the successful version of replace_apk function which was getting 500 from amazon app store.
I

```
def replace_apk(edit_id):
    get_apks_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks' % (APP_ID, edit_id)
    get_apks_url = BASE_URL + get_apks_path
    apks = requests.get(get_apks_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER).json()    
    
    firstAPK = apks[0]
    apk_id = firstAPK['id']   
    get_specific_apk_url = BASE_URL + '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks/%s' % (APP_ID, edit_id, apk_id)
    apk = requests.get(get_specific_apk_url, headers=ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER)
    etag = apk.headers['Etag']
    
    replace_apk_path = '/v1/applications/%s/edits/%s/apks/%s/replace' % (APP_ID, edit_id, apk_id)
    local_apk = open(LOCAL_APK_PATH, 'rb').read()
    _, apk_filename = os.path.split(LOCAL_APK_PATH)
    replace_apk_url = BASE_URL + replace_apk_path
    all_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        'If-Match': etag,
        'fileName': apk_filename
    }
    all_headers.update(ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER)
    replace_apk_response = requests.put(replace_apk_url, headers=all_headers, data=local_apk)
    return replace_apk_response
```

Comment: did you still have the issue?

Comment: No, it resolved some time later. I had an issue with my replace_apk function. It was getting 500. Last version of it is added in the original post. Even if I did not change much of it, it started to function properly